# Can't access array value when my index is a variable

Tags: arrays, arduino, array-indexing

I have a problem accessing a value stored in my 2D array...

When I write the index as a number, it works but when my index is a variable (which contains a number) it does not work...

Here is my code:

```c
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const char eQ1[] PROGMEM = {"En moyenne, combien du temps de notre sommeil passons nous à rêver ? \n 1 -> 10% \n 2 -> 20% \n 3 -> 30% \n 4 -> 40%"};
const char eQ2[] PROGMEM = {"Uranus est proche de : \n 1 -> Mercure \n 2 -> Jupiter \n 3 -> Neptune"};
const char eQ3[] PROGMEM = {"Quelle plante à fleur jaune sert à fabriquer un biocarburant ? \n 1 -> L'arnica \n 2 -> Le colza \n 3 -> Le chrysanthème \n 4 -> Le crocus"};
const char eQ4[] PROGMEM = {"Le paon blanc est un paon albinos: \n 1 -> Vrai \n 2 -> Faux"};
const char eQ5[] PROGMEM = {"Quelle roche transforme-t-on pour fabriquer du plâtre ? \n 1 -> Le gypse \n 2 -> L’argile \n 3 -> Le sable"};
const char eQ6[] PROGMEM = {"Je suis le fruit de l’anacardier. On me grignote à l’apéritif. Qui suis-je ? \n 1 -> La pistache \n 2 -> L’amande \n 3 ->La noix de cajou"};
const char eQ7[] PROGMEM = {"Un arbre peut rejeter plus de 200 litres d’eau dans l’atmosphère en 1h : \n 1 -> Vrai \n 2 -> Faux"};
const char eQ8[] PROGMEM = {"Le bourdon terrestre construit son nid : \n 1 -> Dans les arbres \n 2 -> Sous la terre\n 3 -> Dans les cheminées \n 4 -> Sur l’eau"};
const char eQ9[] PROGMEM = {"A partir de quelle céréale produit-on le saké, un alcool japonais  ? \n 1 -> Le blé \n 2 -> L’avoine\n 3 -> Le riz \n 4 -> Le seigle"};
const char eQ10[] PROGMEM = {"La couleur de l’hortensia dépend de l’acidité du sol : \n 1 -> Vrai \n 2 -> Faux"};
const char eQ11[] PROGMEM = {"Le saucissonier est un arbre : \n 1 -> Vrai \n 2 -> Faux"};


const char * const easyQuestions[11][2] PROGMEM = {
  {eQ1, "2"},
  {eQ2, "3"},
  {eQ3, "2"},
  {eQ4, "2"},
  {eQ5, "1"},
  {eQ6, "3"},
  {eQ7, "1"},
  {eQ8, "2"},
  {eQ9, "3"},
  {eQ10, "1"},
  {eQ11, "1"}
};

int questionsIndex[4] = {};


void setup(){

  // Fill the array with different values

  questionsIndex[0] = random(1, 11);
  questionsIndex[1] = random(1, 11);

  while (questionsIndex[1] == questionsIndex[0]) {
    questionsIndex[1] = random(1, 11);
  }

  questionsIndex[2] = random(1, 11);

  while (questionsIndex[2] == questionsIndex[0] || questionsIndex[2] == questionsIndex[1]) {
    questionsIndex[2] = random(1, 11);
  }

  questionsIndex[3] = random(1, 11);

  while (questionsIndex[3] == questionsIndex[0] || questionsIndex[3] == questionsIndex[1] || questionsIndex[3] == questionsIndex[2]) {
    questionsIndex[3] = random(1, 11);
  }

}

void loop(){

   Serial.print(questionsIndex[0]); // This always returns a different number
   Serial.print(easyQuestions[questionsIndex[0]][1]);
   Serial.println();

/* if I write :
   Serial.print(easyQuestions[3][1]);
   It prints the matching value...
*/

}
```

I've also tried to store the random index into a variable and use this variable as the index but it was not working either...

I am a student and this is for a school project... I am pretty new to Arduino

Thanks by advance !

Comment: If your array is size 11, valid indices are 0-10 not 1-11. 11 is an invalid array reference.
So use `random(0, 10)`. Also, your setup won't guarantee that, for example, question index 2 is different to index 3. It only ensures they're all different to index 0.

Comment: Tha,ks for your answer, I'll fix that first but do you know how can I access my array values ? Because even if my questionIndex is between 0 and 10, it doesn't work...

Comment: You have a similar problem here: `Serial.print(easyQuestions[questionsIndex[0]][1]);` The `1` here is referencing the second element of each row in your 2D array. If you want to write out the question, then you want, `Serial.print(easyQuestions[questionsIndex[0]][0]);`